# UIImageView outlet in grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

I created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` that has an `UIImageView` property called imgView.  My groups have 2 rows only.  The first row, I want to `setImage` on the `UIImageView`, the second row, I want no image.  So I do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
   [cell.imgView setImage:icon];
}
else {
   cell.imgView.hidden = YES;
}
return cell;
```

It works with a cavaet.  Once I scroll down and the cells on top go off screen, my icons start disappearing or reappearing in different rows.  How do I account for this since I use the `[tableView dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier]` method.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show more code. What is row and cell?

Comment: row is the indexPath.row, cell is just my custom cell that has a property of imgView.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using

```
if(cell == nil)
{
     cell = [[[UItableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierRight] autorelease];
}
```

then remove `if(cell == nil)` condition.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  All I needed was to have

```
cell.imgView.hidden = NO;
```

in the first `if (row.indexPath == 0)` block.

Comment: You should just set the image to nil if it != 0. It would be a little bit cleaner that way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your images are dissapearing is because you must first save them to an array, then set the image from the objects in the array. I had the same problem, this works perfect! Also, make sure that the array in a `mutable` array. Hope this helps :D